# Failed to fetch API on CodeSandbox.io with ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, fetch-api

I was able to run it as a local app on `http://localhost:3001` using `npm start`, but if it is used on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-snowflake-1vteb) or Stack Overflow snippet, the fetch fails.  The same if I use the other API http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Los_Angeles

The error:

> GET https://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now
> net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Seems like it may be due to web page on https and fetching data from API using http.

Example here as a live Stack Snippet:

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/pst/now")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(dataFetched => {
        setData(dataFetched);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre className="data">
        {data.currentDateTime}
      </pre> 
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Anybody know why and how to make it work?

Comment: like the fetch cannot return data, but it should be due to https trying to fetch data from http API, I have added to the question

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a result of HTTPS security.

On codesandbox, and here on Stack Snippets, the protocol is **https**. HTTPS pages may only make requests to other HTTPS endpoints. Since the endpoint on worldclockapi you're using is on HTTP, the browser will not try to connect via HTTP.

It may try to upgrade to HTTPS in case the server supports it, but in this case, it doesn't; worldclockapi doesn't support HTTPS at all.

[image]

In contrast, if you run the code on a local file, that local file is *not* loaded over HTTPS, so the restriction doesn't apply; the request to the HTTP endpoint is permitted.

The best solution would be to find a time API that that supports HTTPS; worldclockapi does not appear to be a good choice at the moment, at least not until they upgrade or fix their SSL configuration. You could also downgrade your server hosting this React app to HTTP, but that's a really bad approach.

Comment: I then tried HTTPS for  https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Los_Angeles and it worked.  The display needs to be `{JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}` now because the fields have different names

Comment: @nonopolarity if you manually add the exception for this endpoint (by clicking "navigate - unsafe"), it'll then work, but only on your side. None of your users (if it's meant to be shared publicly or hosted) will be able to use the app without it failing to fetch.